# ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘xml2’

Tags: r, xml2

I am installing "rvest" and "xml2" packages in Ubuntu 16.04. But on multiple times i am getting the error as below

```
/usr/lib/R/etc/Makeconf:143: recipe for target 'connection.o' failed
make: *** [connection.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘xml2’
* removing ‘/home/prdmcl/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/xml2’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘xml2’ had non-zero exit status
```

I checked multiple sources and did this also

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev libssl-dev
sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev
```

But failed to install.

Comment: Could you post the entire log of the installation?

Comment: from where I can see the log of installation?

Comment: I intend all the output you got in the installation, not just the error you reported.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a specific problem with your system(mainly with C++), not with the package.

I had the same problem, and I used this workaround on R command line :

```
withr::with_makevars(c(CXX = "g++ -std=c++11"),install.packages("xml2", verbose = TRUE))
```

This will install xml2. After that, you can install rvest package